# Auto increment using InitNewRow conflicts with SQL Server Sequence

Tags: c#, sql-server

In C# I have the following code to generate the next workorder number in XtraGrid

```
private void gridView1_InitNewRow(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.InitNewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView view = sender as DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView;
    string sqlText = "SELECT MAX([WORK ORDER #]) FROM WORKORDERS ";

    SqlConnection con3 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User ID=sa;Password=password");
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlText, con3);

    try
    {
        con3.Open();
        string pcount = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());

        if (pcount.Length == 0)
        {
            view.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, view.Columns["WORK ORDER #"], "1");
        }
        else
        {
            int pcount1 = Convert.ToInt32(pcount); //pcount;
            int pcountAdd = pcount1 + 1;
            view.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, view.Columns["WORK ORDER #"], pcountAdd.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con3.Close();
    }
}
```

In SQL Server, I have a linked server when `SalesOrder` comes to SQL (SalesOrder or Work Order Process) to generate WORKORDER # I used a `SEQUENCE` as follows

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[WorkOrderSequence] 
 AS [int]
 START WITH 47497
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE -2147483648
 MAXVALUE 2147483647
 CACHE 
GO
```

In my WORKORDER table I have `(4433 row(s))` and the last workorder# is `47493`

Problem when Sales Order to Workorder from Linked server I get the right numbering the problem is when I add a new row into C# grid I get a duplicate record.

Comment: Your grid has concurrency issues. If two people run `SELECT MAX()` a the same time they'll get the same number. Sequence doesn't have that issue

Comment: You should use the sequence in your grid. Don't use select max. As you have discovered it isn't reliable.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks!, how can i use sequence in my grid? ho w can i replace `SELECT MAX()` with `sequence`

Comment: How did you work out how to do SELECT MAX? The answer to your question is only a google away: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql. It's something along the lines of `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.WorkOrderSequence AS NextWorkOrderNumber; `. However I don't understand where the linked server comes into this

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid linked server i shouldn't have to include that here but i wanted to know how to call `dbo.WorkOrderSequence`  at `gridView1_InitNewRow` to get the next number

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid THANK YOU THAT WORKS PERFECT

Comment: Awesome. Can you write your code as an answer and accept it. It'll help other people.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i just replaced  `string sqlText = "SELECT MAX([WORK ORDER #]) FROM WORKORDERS`  with your code `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.WorkOrderSequence AS NextWorkOrderNumber;` everything is the same.